# Run PHP script before website start load by Nginx

Tags: php, apache, nginx

I want run PHP script that found on "/var/www/html/file.php" before load any website on my server.
I have Nginx as reverse-proxy.
I try do it on apache:

```
<Location "/">
    Action pre-script /var/www/html/file.php
    SetHandler pre-script
</Location>
```

But because Nginx is reverse-proxy I need do it on him.
How to do it? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the core php.ini - `auto_prepend_file` directive.

```
Specifies the name of a file that is automatically parsed before the main file. The file is included as if it was called with the require function, so include_path is used.
```

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file

Comment: The problem is `open_basedir` of php.ini and directadmin works And it show me error on every website. I need do it on Apache or Nginx, but I cant found how.

Comment: You have to add the path to the `auto_prepend_file` to your open_basedir, and add the `auto_prepend_file` directive to Apache or Nginx PHP.